# How to redirect backend calls via frontend server to hide backend server details?

Tags: security, nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, mern

### This is my situation...

I am building my first Full Stack Web app using the MERN stack. I will also deploy it on AWS. What I want to know as a newbie is, is there a way to make the backend instance accept requests only from the frontend instance and be completely invisible to the whole internet, or better yet, backend server has no public ip (my knowledge level says - *No Public IP, No Hack Possible*)?

### This is what I know...

I happened to see one of my seniors hosting a website and I saw they used nginx to setup the backend server and then used something called a `proxy_pass` to redirect incoming requests from port 80 to 3000 (where the backend process was running).

When I understood superficially about `proxy_pass`, the idea that came to my head to solve my problem is: What if I route the `api.my-project-website.com` (supposed backend subdomain) also to the frontend and then use the nginx config to proxy_pass it to the ip of the backend server and make it so that the backend only accepts requests from this FE instance's IP.

### This is what I tried...

I tried my own idea and I was successfully able to configure domain/subdomain (`my-project-website.com` and `api.my-project-website.com`) to point to the FE instance via *Route 53* and then use nginx config to proxy_pass the request to the BE server. But the problem here was I was still not able to do it with the Private IP of the BE system. I had to use the Public IP only. I am confused now. Initially I knew the problem was that clients had to send a request directly to the BE server, but now I am using a middle man which my BE knows very well... so why is it not accepting the requests on private IP? Or am I missing something?

### This is what I want...

Is this method useful? will it even work? or am I thinking in the wrong way? Will it achieve the level of security, as I mentioned earlier? Or is it still breachable *easily* (I know nothing is fool-proof)? If this idea won't solve the issue, can anyone give me another solution? or just help me with the right direction to think in? I would love to explore on my own, just need some initial guidance!

<kbd>Logic Kahan Hai</kbd>